# Android Not Redrawing after View.layout(l,t,r,b)

Tags: android, animation, view

I am attempting to place several images at specific points on my layout using ImageButton.layout(l,t,r,b).  After they are arranged, I would like to execute an animation on each ImageButton.  The trouble is, the animation starts before the positions of the ImageButtons has changed on the screen, causing the animation to look wrong.

How can I fix this?  Here is a bit of code...

```
private void arrangeButtons() 
{
  int temp = 0;
  for(ImageButton imageButtonButton :imageButtonList) {
    imageButtonButton.setCurrentPositionIndex(temp);
    int l = PositionsLeft[temp];
    int t = PositionsTop[temp];
    int r = PositionsRight[temp];
    int b = positionsBottom[temp];
    currentButton.layout(l,t,r,b);
    temp++;
  }
  ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.imageListFrame);
  vg.invalidate();
  vg.refreshDrawableState();
}
public static void rotateButtons() {
  for(ImageButton imageButton : imageButtonList) {
    RotateAnimation rotation = new RotateAnimation(0, 45, 25, 25);
    imageButton.setAnimation(rotation);
    imageButton.startAnimation(rotations);
  }
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  arrangeButtons();
  rotateButtons();
}
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `requestLayout()` after `currentButton.layout(l,t,r,b);` or better yet use `setLayoutParams` to change the position of the view on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I am now using setLayoutParams, however I have discovered the root of the problem.  I removed the animation for now, and found that even when using setLayoutParams, the topMargin rightMargin etc all get reset to (0,0,0,42) by the time onCreate has completed.  Why is this happening?!  Any help is greatly appreciated lol, I'm pretty stumped...

Comment: Probably you are setting the margins in the xml? Also where's your call to super.onCreate()?

Comment: The code I posted is boiled down [I have the super call].

I thought it could be the xml overwriting the position, so I extended LinearLayout and overrode onFinishInflate and called arrangeButtons from there and encountered the same problem.

Quite the problem I've found haha...