# android - positioning a view using layout(l,t,r,b) doesn't work for the first draw

Tags: android, layout, position

I am creating a view programmatically and adding it to the rootview of my activity. When it is created, it is positioned absolutely to coincide with another view and then animated to grow and possibly shift a bit to stay on screen. All of this works well, but right before the animation starts, the new view flashes on the screen in the upper left-hand corner instead of its correct position!

On initializing the view, I call layout(l,t,r,b) and its onLayout() function is called back with the correct numbers. I set up the animation, and the execution returns to the event loop and handles other things.

Then, onLayout is called by the system with new (wrong) numbers, placing my view in the upper left corner (at 0,0), where it is then drawn. If I don't have an animation set up, that is where it stays.

With the animation, onDraw is not called again and I don't usually get callbacks to the animator listener for start and repeat, but I get the end callback, at which point my view is positioned correctly. In the emulator and on devices, after flashing for one frame in the upper left corner, the view goes to its correct position, plays through the animation, and remains in the correct position.

I want to get rid of that flash!

I think this question comes close to the problem, but there is no solution:
[Android Not Redrawing after View.layout(l,t,r,b)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8512087/7439163)

Here is a simplified form of the problem view:

```
class SampleView (val originalView: View) : FrameLayout(originalView.context) {
val TAG = "SampleView"
val self = this

val myRect = Rect()
val parentRect = Rect()




override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDraw: " + left + "," + top)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}

override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLayout: changed? " + changed.toString() + " -- " + listOf(left, top, right, bottom).joinToString(","))
    /* try {
         throw Exception("where are we?")
     } catch (e: Exception) {
         Log.e(TAG, "HERE: ", e)
     }
    */
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
}

init {

    setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)

    // delay rest of initialization until parent is known
    addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewDetached")
        }

        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewAttached")

            //set initial size and position
            layoutParams.width = 50
            layoutParams.height = 50
            layout(100, 100, 150, 150)

            val rootCoords = intArrayOf(-1,-1)
            getLocationInWindow(rootCoords)
            Log.d(TAG,"sampleView at: " + rootCoords.joinToString(","))
            Log.d(TAG, "sampleView: " + layoutParams.width + "x" + layoutParams.height + " " + left + "," + top)

            doAnimation()
        }
    })

}

fun doAnimation() {

    val ZOOM = 2
    val SHIFT = 10f

    // predict new size and center position
    Log.d(TAG, "sampleView (final): " +
            (originalView.width * ZOOM).toString() + "x" + (originalView.height * ZOOM).toString() +
            " " + (x+SHIFT) + "," + (y + SHIFT))

    // animate to new size and position
    val animator = this.animate()
    animator.scaleX((ZOOM).toFloat())
    animator.scaleY((ZOOM).toFloat())
    animator.xBy(SHIFT)
    animator.yBy(SHIFT)
    animator.duration = 500

    animator.start()

    animator.setListener(object: Animator.AnimatorListener {
        val TAG = "AnimatorListener"

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
            val arr = intArrayOf(-1, -1)
            self.getLocationInWindow(arr)
            Log.d(TAG, "animation repeat at: " + arr.joinToString(","))
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            val arr = intArrayOf(-1, -1)
            self.getLocationInWindow(arr)
            Log.d(TAG, "animation end at: " + arr.joinToString(","))
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            val arr = intArrayOf(-1, -1)
            self.getLocationInWindow(arr)
            Log.d(TAG, "animation cancel: " + arr.joinToString(","))
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
            val arr = intArrayOf(-1, -1)
            self.getLocationInWindow(arr)
            Log.d(TAG, "animation start at: " + arr.joinToString(","))
        }
    })
}

}
```

and the resulting log, starting with the function that creates the view and attaches it to the root:

```
    10-03 17:48:00.266 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/ImageInputIME: preview icon
10-03 17:48:00.270 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: onViewAttached
10-03 17:48:00.273 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: onLayout: changed? true -- 100,100,150,150
10-03 17:48:00.273 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: sampleView at: 100,100
10-03 17:48:00.274 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: sampleView: 50x50 100,100
10-03 17:48:00.274 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: sampleView (final): 92x94 110.0,110.0
10-03 17:48:00.279 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SwipePagerView: onInterceptTouch: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=432.71362, y[0]=37.5625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=32059219, downTime=32059206, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
10-03 17:48:00.279 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/SwipePagerView: sent to trails
10-03 17:48:00.279 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SwipePagerView: sent to swiper
10-03 17:48:00.279 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SwipeListener: UP
10-03 17:48:00.279 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/InputPageView: isInView(437.71362,111.5625): Rect(82, 84 - 129, 131)
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/InputPageView: isInView(437.71362,111.5625): Rect(149, 84 - 196, 131)
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/InputPageView: isInView(437.71362,111.5625): Rect(216, 84 - 263, 131)
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/InputPageView: isInView(437.71362,111.5625): Rect(283, 84 - 330, 131)
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/InputPageView: isInView(437.71362,111.5625): Rect(350, 84 - 397, 131)
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard V/InputPageView: isInView(437.71362,111.5625): Rect(417, 84 - 463, 131)
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/InputPageView: releaseIconHandler -- 6watch: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=432.71362, y[0]=37.5625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=32059219, downTime=32059206, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/ImageInputIME: execute icon
10-03 17:48:00.280 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/ImageInputIME: typeIcon: watch
10-03 17:48:00.282 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: onLayout: changed? true -- 0,0,50,50
10-03 17:48:00.284 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/SampleView: onDraw: 0,0
10-03 17:48:00.288 8523-8540/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434c40: ver 2 0
10-03 17:48:00.342 8523-8540/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434c40: ver 2 0
10-03 17:48:00.348 8523-8540/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434c40: ver 2 0
10-03 17:48:00.775 8523-8523/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/AnimatorListener: animation end at: 85,85
10-03 17:48:00.859 8523-8540/com.hyperana.kindleimagekeyboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434c40: ver 2 0
```

If you understand what is going on, I appreciate your insight. I can think of a few ways to get around positioning it in this instance, but I'd like to know how to do it right if I should really need to :)

Comment: specify `android:layout_gravity` to be different that the default "upper-left" position

Comment: @pskink -- That does have an effect (or rather setting gravity does, because I don't think I can set layout-gravity programmatically). If I put it to center, it flashes in the center instead of the corner. I suppose this means I should use margins in the layoutparams to position it...I'll try that, but what is calling layout() doing that doesn't seem to take effect until the second draw?

Comment: if you want it on the bottom of the parent use gravity="bottom", if you want it on the right edge use gravity="right" etc, see similar views like [Snackbar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/3224093af46bac6f2fd5b372d5fbd56429b811c1/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java) for example - note then how to animate it: `animateViewIn` / `animateViewOut`

Comment: I want it wherever I put it :) The idea is to position it at runtime based on where other views are on the screen regardless of the view tree or whatever (I can add this view to any viewgroup in the tree and line it up with any other view in the tree). It may be that there is no nice way to do this.

Comment: so see how above `animateViewIn` / `animateViewOut` methods are placing the snackbar on the screen

Comment: @pskink-- Thanks, got it. I will use view.translationX and translationY to set its position instead of layout() -- this seems to take effect right away.